# Query works fine in SSMS but gives this error in C# "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute a very long and complicated SQL server query in my C# code.
It's several days that I'm stuck with this error and I can't figure out where it comes from.It's most probably comes from somewhere in the following block of code, although it's just a tiny part of my whole query.

I checked the names of columns and matching of number of columns in insert statements hundreds of times and nothing seems to be wrong.
Also I used debugging and copied the query in the instance of error into MS SSMS and it runs without any error. Still in C# I receive this error.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

```
         string my_query =  
        " IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp_table " +
        " IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table') IS NULL " +
        " BEGIN " +
        " CREATE TABLE  #temp_table " +
        " ( [ID] int NOT NULL ," +
        "   [Name] [varchar](20)   not null , " +
        "   [Address] [varchar](100)   not null , " +
        "   CONSTRAINT [PK_3] PRIMARY KEY ( [ID] desc )  )  " + 
        " END " +  

        " insert into #temp_table " +
        " select max([ID]) as [ID], [Name] ,[Address]  " +
        " FROM [my_DB].[dbo].[my_table] s " +
        " where substring(s.[Address],1,16) not like 'some_pattern'  " + 
        " group by [Name] ,[Address] " ;


        SqlCommand my_command = new SqlCommand(my_query , conn)
        my_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Edit**:
Solved. The problem was that the name of my temp_table was used somewhere else in another command in my C# code and I thought the temp tables are removed after each query command.

Comment: Why not just use `select into`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and printing the query text from your variable and testing it in SQL directly to see the error?

Comment: Hi Gordon. Is it the reason that I get error? I think insert should work as well. I don't use ```Select into``` because this way I have more control over naming of my keys and also there are more insert into this table and not just this one.

Comment: @Brad, as I wrote in the post, I did it and there was no error there.

Comment: Are you sure you are targetting the correct database in your C# code?

Comment: The code looks fine, but you should always specify columns when inserting:  insert into #temp_table  (col list here) as best practice.  You can try that to see if it works as compiler may not understand without that

Comment: Also I am assuming you are doing work with the temp table after somewhere?  Because temp tables are removed/no longer exist after your connection is closed, so if you dont use it in same  connection it no longer exists.  So this would  be better done in Stored Procedure I believe.

Comment: The database is correct. I tried to mention the names of columns in insert statement and I receive a new error. It says that my last column name [Address] is invalid. I checked the spelling and everything is correct.

Comment: Solved. The problem was that the name of my temp_table was used somewhere in another command in my C# code and I thought the temp tables are removed after each query command. Thank you all.

Comment: If you use the same connection the temp tables will stay, if you close and open the connection the temp tables will be dropped.  Though you were checking to see if it existed, and then drop it, so not sure how it could be using one from previous query if you check/drop it.  If you add a GO after the temp table exists and create should solve for that.

Comment: @Brad I think the problem comes from this annoying thing in SQL that the keys are object independent of the table and when you delete the table, the key still persists. Although I even tried to remove the key itself, before deleting the table(alter table drop key drop table). I don't know...